# Возвести в квадрат все числа в списке

Tags: python

Хочу изменить все числы в списке на квадратичную форму, написал код, но выдает ошибку. Как можно решить?

```
numbers = list(range(1,11))
for number in numbers:
    number = number **2
    print(numbers)
```

Comment: Какую ошибку выдаёт код?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я думаю, что в данном случае ошибкой назван не тот результат, которого ожидали

Comment: @Павел, я с вами согласен. Хочется чтобы ТС выразился понятно. "Ошибка", "цифры", "квадратичная форма" - всё этого не должно быть если в голове ясность.

Comment: Извините, была ошибка **IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level** но потом просто выводит список десять раз. Вместо **print(numbers)** написал **print(number)**, выводит квадраты чисел но не в списке, а по отдельности

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Несколько вариантов:

1. Чуть иной вариант от Павла:

   ```py
   numbers = list(range(1,11))
   square_numbers = [x * x for x in numbers]
   print(square_numbers) # [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
   ```

Недостаток генератора списков в том, что он создает новый список в памяти целиком. Для небольших списков это не принципиально, но для больших структур Вы рискуете столкнуться с исключением нехватки памяти.

2. Немного меняем код - квадратные скобки заменим на круглые.

   ```py
   gen_result = (x * x for x in numbers)
   square_numbers = list(gen_result)
   print(square_numbers)  # [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
   ```

Получим выражение-генератор, элементы которого вычисляются в момент обращения к ним. Полученное выражение-генератор можно перебрать в цикле for или вызывая метод next. При этом решается проблема генератора списков из предыдущего пункта - расход памяти. Но есть одно НО: выражение-генератор можно перебрать только один раз. В приведенном примере кода выражение-генератор преобразуется в список (но можно в кортеж, множество или словарь), что вызывает автоматический перебор элементов.

3. Наконец вариант с применением функции map.

   ```py
   square_function = lambda x: x * x
   gen_result = map(square_function, numbers)
   square_numbers = list(gen_result)
   print(square_numbers)  # [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
   ```

Или более кратко:

```
square_numbers = list(map(lambda x: x * x, numbers))
print(square_numbers)  # [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```

Функция map возвращает объект-итератор, похожий на выражение-генератор из пункта 2. Мощь функции map в том, что к списку поэлементно можно применить практически любую функцию, в том числе и самописную, и выполнить над списком практически любые вычисления. Кстати, можно обработать сразу несколько списков. Для примера, применим стандартную функцию возведения в степень (можно применить аналогичные функции из библиотек numpy или math):

```
square_numbers = list(map(pow, numbers, [2 for _ in numbers]))
print(square_numbers)  # [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```

4. На последок, если стоит задача заменить элементы исходного списка без создания нового (для экономии памяти):

   ```py
   numbers = list(range(1,11))
   numbers[:] = list(map(lambda x: x * x, numbers))
   ```

Либо сразу:

```
numbers = list(map(lambda x: x * x, range(1,11)))
```

Или так:

```
numbers = list(x * x for x in range(1,11))
```

Answer (score 2):

Проблем в коде две:

1. Выводить содержимое списка `print(numbers)` стоит после завершения цикла `for`
2. Строка `number = number **2` не меняет содержимое списка, а просто создает новую переменную с именем `number`, которая не имеет со списком ничего общего.

Для изменения списка следует воспользоваться присваиванием по индексу (`a[i] = ...`), методами `.append(), .insert(), .remove(),` ....

Вообще, такое преобразование делается при помощи [генератора списков](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) в одну строку:

```
a = [1,2,3]

b = [x ** 2 for x in a]

print(b) # [1,4,9]
```